# Display messages from "> /dev/null"?

Tags: bash

Bash amateur here, sorry for the stupid question. I am having an issue where echo messages are not being displayed from a function I'm calling (removeBlade in this case). I know the reason is because of > /dev/null, but I put that there to hide an irrelevant error I was receiving (parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 11 - even though the script still ran correctly after the fact, and googling did not give me any relevant solutions for that error). So, how can get I my echo messages to appear from the removeBlade function while still suppressing the parser error?

```
    local vJson="$@"
    local vId=$(echo "$vJson" | jq .id)
    local vMethod=$(echo "$vJson" | jq .method | tr -d '"\n')
        
    case "$vMethod" in
        RemoveBlade)
              bladeVal=$(echo "$vJson" | jq .removeBladeParams[0].blade | tr -d '"\n')
              removeBlade $bladeVal > /dev/null
```

Comment: Error messages are usually written to `stderr`, so you filter them out with `2>/dev/null`. Is `removeBlade` writing them to stdout instead?

Comment: BTW, `jq` has a built-in mechanism to print strings without quotes around them, you should use that instead of piping to `tr`.

Comment: I'd try to identify the character your parser is choking on, better fix the cause of the warning than try to hide it, in particular since it might hide future warnings or error you'd want to know of. You've certainly already looked at the content of `$bladeVal`, but you might have missed a control character since those are not visible by default. There are a lot of ways to change that, my go-to is to use `cat -A` to print those characters as their [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation). I'd add `cat -A <<< "$bladeVal"` after the line where you define `bladeVal`

Comment: Barmar: it does appear it is being written to stdout. I tried to filter it out with 2> with no success. Aaron: Interesting take on it, but unfortunately all it did was suppress the echo messages I do want to see and displayed the error, so the opposite of the solution i'm looking for :)

Comment: I you really don't want to deal with the root cause, you can pipe ther output through `grep`. Use something like `removeBlade $bladeVal | grep -v "parse error"` (Adjust it to pick up only the error message you do want to remove.)

Comment: @blindside044 I didn't meant to use the command I provided as a permanent fix but merely as a way to debug your code. The caret notation that `cat -A` outputs is sure to make your parser fail, my suggestion was to read it yourself to see if there's anything weird

Comment: In particular I would look for `^M` at the end of lines (the `$` is expected though, it's the `\n` linefeed), and it would also show unicode characters that aren't part of the ascii set and might not suit your parser in some specific way I can't remember

Comment: hange `removeBlade $bladeVal` into `removeBlade "$bladeVal"` avoiding the shell to parse the output. Are you in control of the function `removeBlade` ?